# Find a record in dbSet using Find without a primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a users table:

```
Users:
 +ID
 +Username
 +...
```

I want to use `myDBContext.Users.Find(Username)` to fin a users.
in my current context I can not use his ID.

do i have to use a full LINQ query ? e.g.

```
var user = from users in myDBContext.Users.Find(Username) 
           where users.Username == username
           select users
```

I have also tried to define the username as a primary key in my edmx but that resulted in the following error:

> Properties referred by the Principal Role User must be exactly
>   identical to the key of the EntityType
>   CamelotShiftManagementModel.User referred to by the Principal Role in
>   the relationship constraint for Relationship
>   CamelotShiftManagementModel.AssociationUserFK1. Make sure all the key
>   properties are specified in the Principal
>   Role. C:\Code\CamelotShiftManagement\CamelotShiftManagement\Models\CamelotDB.edmx 278 11  CamelotShiftManagement

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try with,

```
User myUser = myDBContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.Username == username);
```

Use `SingleOrDefault` insted of `Single`. If user doesn't exist then `Single` will throw an error. While `SingleOrDefault` will return `null` if user not found otherwise `User` object will be return.

**Selection Between `SingleOrDefault` and `FirstOrDefault`**

You can get the user object by using `SingleOrDefault` and `FirstOrDefault` but while selecting which method to use consider below points.

- Both return only one value from collection/database if exist otherwise default value.
- But if you have more than one user with same name and you are expecting to get an exception while performing LINQ query then use `SingleOrDefault` as it will thrown an exception if there are more than one element available.
- And if you don't want exception and/or you don't want to check that your collection/database have duplication of data, just want to get first value from collection/database then use `FirstOrDefault` for better performance compare to `SingleOrDefault`

**`FirstOrDefault`**

- Generally `FirstOrDefault` or `First` used when we required single value (first) from the collection or database.
- In the case of First / FirstOrDefault, only one row is retrieved from the database so it performs slightly better than single / SingleOrDefault. such a small difference is hardly noticeable but when table contain large number of column and row, at this time performance is noticeable.

**Some other remarks**

- If `username` is primary key then I think there will be no (significant) difference between `SingleOrDefault` and `FirstOrDefault` performance as primary key has index and search on index column will always be faster than normal column.
- `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` will generate a regular TSQL like "SELECT ...".
- The `First` or `FirstOrDefault` method will generate the TSQL statment like "SELECT TOP 1..."

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `FirstOrDefault` instead? My understanding of the `SingleOrDefault` method is that it will browse the *whole* table to make sure that only one record matches the condition. It may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Crono Yes you are right for FirstOrDefault if we consider performance of it compare to SingleOrDefault. But Here I think depending on expected result we should do selection between these two methods. If you want only single result and you are expecting an exception if there more than one sequence of same then use SinleOrDefault otherwise use FirstOrDefault. I will Update my answer with this context.

Comment: @Crono I hope above my updated answer will provide detail understanding on `SingleOrDefault` and `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 5):

I've found it:

```
User myUser = myDBContext.Users.Single(user => user.Username == i_Username);
```

Comment: Yes it is ok, but you should accept it as answer since it is the solution for your problem.

Comment: Well it tells me i can only accept it in two days so i'll wait.. tnx

Comment: @Mortalus find my answer if it help to your question. I just changed Single to SingleOrDefault.